# TCP 30 small packets per second flood connection with server

Tags: networking, tcp, ping

I'm testing connection with flash client and cloud server(`boost::asio` for software) over TCP connection. My connection with server already is really poor - 120 ms ping in average. I found when i start to send packets with 2 bytes size (without tcp header) with speed 30 packets/s - ping grow to 170-200 average. I think that it's really bad and my bad connection and bad cloud provider is reason for this high ping without any load. What do you think? (I tested my software - it can compute about 50k small packets/s so software is not a problem).

I measure my ping through flash client - send packet with timestamp and immediatly send from server to client.

Comment: Note that when he says "ping", he actually means application response time measured over *TCP*. (He mentions this in his last paragraph, but it's easy to miss it.)

Comment: Did you actually measure 30 small packets per second on the network? Or are you assuming that you're getting 30 small packets per second because you're doing 30 small writes per second?

Comment: Yes i do 30 small writes with simple data structure without disconnecting and i call it packet

Comment: Learn a valuable lesson and never do that again. If you start confusing application-level TCP concepts with network-level TCP concepts, you'll never get TCP right. :)

Comment: I'd like to use UDP for transfering small chunks of data but web flash player doesn't support it

Comment: You can use TCP, you just have to avoid small writes. (Why are you doing small writes anyway? Why can't you aggregate this data yourself?)

Comment: I'm making 2D action rpg with WASD movement and for now i send 30 key updates to server, this is only movement + sometimes will send attack buttons + spell buttons

Comment: Okay, change your design as follows: 1) If there's no change, don't send an update. 2) When the server receives an update, it should reply to it immediately. A single byte "I got it" is fine. 3) Don't let more than one update be "in flight" at a time. That is, if you haven't received a reply to the previous update, don't send another one. 4) Do **NOT** disable Nagle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6201/discussion-between-denis-ermolin-and-david-schwartz)

Comment: I opened chat room for couple of questions

Answer (score 1):

> My connection with server already is really poor - 120 ms ping in average.

I did a similar test to `www.google.com`, testing response time over TCP, and got 160 milliseconds. Does Google have poor connectivity? TCP was not designed for quick response times.

> I measure my ping through flash client - send packet with timestamp and immediatly send from server to client.

TCP, by design, delays up to 200 milliseconds to provide more effective network utilization. You are not measuring anything except TCP specifically doing what it is designed to do. If you look closely at the network traffic, you'll see that most of the TCP packets actually contain much more than two bytes of data.

You are expecting horribly inefficient behavior. Sending 30 packets per second each containing only two bytes of data is incredibly dumb and TCP isn't stupid enough to do that.

Two suggestions:

Don't call this "ping". That makes people think it's a network round-trip measurement rather than a measurement of response time over TCP.

Don't say "30 packets/s" unless you actually measured the network traffic. When you write some bytes to a TCP connection, there is no reason to expect that will correspond to a packet. Packets are network things. Writes to a TCP connection are application things. Confusing application and network level concepts will really mess you up when you deal with TCP.

Also, why are you doing so many small writes? Gather the data into larger writes. Yes, TCP will do this for you, but it's still much more efficient if you do this in your application.

If you're just doing these horrible small writes to test performance, just stop doing it. It won't give you useful data. If these horrible small writes replicate your actual usage scenario and response time is important, then you need to work on fixing your protocol so that it makes some kind of sense.

Comment: I have turned of Nagle's algorithm on server side, but i dont sure that flash application flushes buffer without delay

Comment: That's very bad. You're intentionally giving TCP a horrible situation and then you're disabling the mechanism it uses to cope with precisely that horrible situation! The only time you disable Nagle is when you have an application that wasn't designed with TCP in mind.